90s/2000s movie about a woman who was sent to an asylum, escapes, and throws herself off a bridge
This film was from the 1990s/2000s and was made in the US. The protagonist is a woman, with short, black hair.

One scene of the movie has a flashback of the woman protagonist as child who is, I think, given electric shock therapy whilst strapped to a table
The woman protagonist then escapes with the help of another asylum patient. I think the patient kills a nurse with a screwdriver
Towards the end of the movie the woman, wearing a red dress, apparently commits suicide, despite the attempts of the police, by throwing herself off a high bridge and into the river.


You're looking for "In Dreams". You got most of the plot right, insane asylum,flashbacks, protagonist with short hair & red dress. She kills herself by jumping into water. 
There's more to it,of course, but it's a really weird movie.
Worth it if you want to see Robert Downey Jr as a nutcase.



In Dreams (1999)

Claire Cooper dreams strange things from time to time. One night, she dreams about a little girl being taken away by a stranger, right in her neighbourhood. When her own daughter Rebecca is kidnapped and murdered only a little later, Claire is sure about the chilling truth that her and the killer's mind are connected to each other in dreams. But nobody believes her being able to foresee the killer's next steps, as she could with her own daughter. In addition, the nervous breakdown she suffers gets her into a mental facility after a suicide attempt. And here, locked away in a padded cell, she dreams of her husband being murdered...

